# Confusion related to changing the order of integrals.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let's say we have this double integral: $$\int_0^1\int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy\,dx $$

$x$ is from $0$ to $1,$ and $y$ is from $0$ to the line $y=x.$
when we swap the order of the integral we get: $$\int_0^1\int_y^1 f(x,y) \, dx \, dy $$ 
$x$ is from the line $x=y$ to $1,$ and $y$ is now from $0$ to $1.$ Please explain to me two things:

a. does the variable in the limit always need to be in the inner integral?

b. why can't i view $x$ as still being from $0$ to $1$ when changing the order of the integral instead of $y$ to $1.$ it still makes sense in the Region of Integration, no?

Comment: Regarding b. Have you visualized the region you are sugesting? $0<x<1$ , $0<y<1$ is a square of unit side.

Comment: oh right. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy\right) \,dx = \iint\limits_{0\,\le\,y\,\le\, x\,\le\,1} f(x,y) \, d(x,y) = \int_0^1 \left( \int_y^1 f(x,y)\, dx \right) dy 
$$
One could say that the integrals on the left and right above are equal to each other because they are both equal to the integral in the middle.

This may be easier to illustrate using sums:
\begin{align}
& \sum_{x\,=\,1}^3 \left( \sum_{y\,=\,1}^x a(x,y) \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \phantom{{}+{}} a(1,1) & \longleftarrow\quad & x=1 \\
& {} + a(2,1) + a(2,2) & \longleftarrow\quad & x=2 \\
& {} + a(3,1) + a(3,2) + a(3,3) & \longleftarrow\quad & x=3 \\[10pt]
= {} & \phantom{{}+{}} a(1,1) \\
& {} + a(2,1)+a(2,2) \\
& {} + a(3,1)+a(3,2)+a(3,3) \\
& \qquad \uparrow \qquad\qquad\uparrow\qquad\quad\uparrow \\
& \quad y=1\qquad y=2 \qquad y=3 \\[15pt]
= {} & \sum_{y\,=\,1}^3\left( \sum_{x\,=\,y}^3 a(x,y) \right)
\end{align}
Both of the iterated sums above are equal to $\displaystyle \sum_{x,y\,:\, 1\,\le\,y\,\le\,x\,\le\,3} a(x,y).$

**Postscript suggested in a comment below from Mark Viola:**

Changing the order in some cases alters the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{x,y} a(x,y)$ (without absolute value signs) when $\displaystyle \sum_{x,y} |a(x,y)|= +\infty$ (with absolute value), and likewise with integrals.

Comment: Hi Michael.  You might consider adding a statement that highlights the fact that interchanging the order of integration is not always permissible.

Comment: thank you for the sum analogy. does the variable in the limit always need to be in the inner integral?

Comment: @SyedBukhari: of course, if the limit is tied to the other variable

Comment: @SyedBukhari : If there is a variable in the outer integral, then the value of the expression as a whole is a function of that variable. Thus in $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^x f(x,y)\,dy\right) \,dx.$ the inner integral is a function of $x,$ and in the outer integral one is integrating a function of $x$ with respect to $x.$ Now consider the point where it says $\text{“}\quad\longleftarrow x=2\quad\text{''}\quad$ in the answer above. You have $y$ going from $1$ to $x$ (where $x=2$ in the sum $a(2,1)+a(2,2).$ But in the row below that you have$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,y$ going from $1$ to $x,$ where $x=3$ in the sum $a(3,1)+a(3,2)+a(3,3).$ What would $\text{“}x\text{''}$ mean if it were a bound in the outer sum? Would it be $2$ or $3$ or what? $\qquad$

Comment: that clarifies it pretty well. thank you.

Comment: @SyedBukhari : Note that you can "accept" this answer.

Comment: lol sorry. I'm new to this website. didn't know one had to do so. anyway, done.

Comment: @SyedBukhari : You don't _have_ to do that. Normally it is done with the best one among fully satisfactory answers.